# how to strip html whitespace and comment and javascript comments using nokogiri?

Tags: html, ruby, nokogiri

I'm looking for a way in nokogiri to strip out html whitespace & comment and javascript comment (/* */, //). I'm doing this not because of the size of the document. I'm playing around with rack middleware to do this job. I know I could do via regular expression, but i think it could be troublesome.

If not possible to do with nokogiri, please give me the best regular expression to strip out for the 2 above cases.

What I tried using regular expression:

```
response = @app.call(env)
body = response.last.body.gsub(/(\n|\t|\r)/, ' ').gsub(/>\s*</, '><').gsub(/<!--[^>]*-->/, ' ').squeeze(' ')
response.last.body = body
response
```

I think there should be a cleaner way to do rather than using regular expression.

Comment: This question doesn't show what you already tried, or what specific problems you got stuck on. See http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask, especially "based on actual problems that you face".

Comment: alright, i updated the question to state what I have already tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up writing a [middleware](https://github.com/chamnap/html_compressor_middleware/blob/master/lib/html_compressor.rb) to handle this since there is no exact solution for this.
Here I use very strict regular expression to handle it.

Check the code on my github repo.

Answer (score 3):

Loofah is nice but it won't help you strip javascript comments.

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522733/removing-comments-in-javascript-using-ruby) deals with stripping js comments but there seems to be much disagreement. I agree with the ones who say you should not do it. However if you wanted to try the accepted answer with loofah you might do:

```
require 'rubygems'
require "loofah"

scrubber = Loofah::Scrubber.new do |node|
    node.content = node.content.strip if node.name == "text"
    node.remove if node.name == "comment"
    if node.cdata? && node.parent.name == "script"
        node.content = node.content.gsub(/\/\*![^*]*\*+(?:[^*\/][^*]*\*+)*\//,'')
    end
end

puts Loofah.fragment('<p> trim </p><!-- remove --><p> me </p><script>var x=0;/*! remove! */</script>').scrub!(scrubber)

# <p>trim</p><p>me</p><script>var x=0;</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Loofah might be what you are looking for:

https://github.com/flavorjones/loofah